# Using GOOGLE MAPS DirectionsService/ DirectionsRenderer properly in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I have yet to find some documentation or equivalent that shows how to use the **DirectionsService** and **DirectionsRenderer** in newer React versions with hooks.

**My state**

```
  const [origin, setOrigin] = useState(null)
  const [destination, setDestination] = useState(null)
  const [directions, setDirections] = useState(null)
```

`onClick` I call `handleSetDirectionParams` and set an `origin` and a `destination` to their own piece of state:

```
  const handleSetDirectionParams = () => {
    setOrigin({ latitude: userLocation.lat, longitude: userLocation.lat })
    setDestination({ latitude: active.latitude, longitude: active.longitude })
  }
```

If these values exist, I am trying to render the directions route from marker to marker in my googleMap component:

```
        {origin && destination ? (
          <DirectionsService
            options={{
              destination: destination,
              origin: origin,
              travelMode: 'DRIVING'
            }}
            callback={directionsCallback}
          />
        ) : null}
        {directions && (
          <DirectionsRenderer directions={directions} />
        )}
```

**directionsCallback**

```
  const directionsCallback = (response) => {
    console.log(response)

    if (response !== null) {
      if (response.status === 'OK') {
        setDirections(response)
      } else {
        console.log('response: ', response)
      }
    }
  }
```

I currently receive this `errorMessage`

```
InvalidValueError: in property origin: not a string; and not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number; and unknown property latitude
```

from my understanding `destination` and `origin` are able to take an object with a latitude and longitude property? Any help here would be great.

Comment: They can take an object in form of a [Lat/Lng Literal](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-latlng-literal). The error message lists both a string _and_ a Lat/Lng Literal as valid types. Have you tried using `lat` and `lng` as properties in your object as in `{ lat: userLocation.lat, lng: userLocation.lng }`? It looks the end of the error message mentions `unknown property latitude` so wondering if that could be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> from my understanding destination and origin are able to take an object with a latitude and longitude property?

This is incorrect. It must be a [LatLng instance](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLng), an interface implementing [LatLngLiteral](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLngLiteral), or a string of the appropriate format.

Using the LatLngLiteral interface:

```js
  const handleSetDirectionParams = () => {
    setOrigin({ lat: userLocation.lat, lng: userLocation.lat })
    setDestination({ lat: active.latitude, lng: active.longitude })
  }
```